# How can I justify my cursor to line up with my output colums in a terminal program?

Tags: c++, formatting

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

const double PI = 3.14159;
double rad = 0;
double area = 0;
double vol = 0;
int areaPi = 0;
int volPi = 0;

cout << setprecision(5) << fixed;
cout << setw(38) << left << "Enter radius for the sphere: " << right);
cin  >> rad;

area = (4 * PI * (rad * rad));
vol = ((4.0/3.0) * PI * (rad * rad * rad));
areaPi = (4 * (rad *rad));
volPi = (4 * (rad * rad * rad));

cout << right << "Surface area of the sphere: " << setw(12) << area << " (" << areaPi << "\u03C0)";
cout << "\n";
cout << "The volume of the sphere: " << setw(14) << vol << " (" << volPi << "π/3)";
cout << "\n";

return 0;
}
```

Hi guys. So the problem I'm having is that when you enter a value for the radius (rad) variable the cursor wants to work its way from the left to the right when the user types resulting in double digit numbers being longer than the output columns.

It looks like this when the program runs and you enter anything longer than one digit:

```
//Enter radius for the sphere:           17
//Surface area of the sphere:   3631.67804 (1156π)
//The volume of the sphere:    20579.50889 (19652π/3)
```

I would like the 7 to line up with the column below it. I tried setting the width to one less than I had before & single digits end up one space too far to the left like so:

```
//Enter radius for the sphere:          4
//Surface area of the sphere:    201.06176 (64π)
//The volume of the sphere:      268.08235 (256π/3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store the output into a set of strings. Then you could check and manipulate the data as needed. Alternatively you could calculate the offset of spaces you'd need before printing

```
 // convert to string for digit count
std::string output_1 = std::to_string(x);
std::string output_2 = std::to_string(y);
int o_1_2_dist = output_1.size() - output_2.size(); // difference in digits
std::string padding_1, padding_2;
if (o_1_2_dist < 0)
    padding_1 = std::string(abs(o_1_2_dist), ' ');
else
    padding_2 = std::string(o_1_2_dist, ' ');
std::cout << padding_1 << output_1 << '\n' << padding_2 << output_2;
```

you'd want to adjust on of the output strings so it doesn't count the extra bits of the number you don't care about. Maybe do `output_1 = std::to_string(floor(x));` or something like that so you don't count the digits after the decimal

Comment: Thanks! I had to turn the assignment in the way it was as I see I'm going to need to understand a bit more. BUT I will be trying to fix my code this weekend and try to understand what you're saying and apply it to my code. We haven't gotten to strings yet in class (comp sci 1A ) so I'll do my best. Maybe it's time to read ahead.

Comment: you could manually count the digits by dividing by exponents of ten, then use that to print spaces in a for loop of `std::cout << ' '` :P

Comment: Ok I'll try that too! Every example helps me so thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by calculating the length of the input. I used c++11's `to_string` to convert the resulting values to strings and find out their lengths. I haven't tried how portable that is. It seems to work under linux with gcc 6.1.1., but for some reason it did not work with the input, so I changed that part as well so that the users enters a `std::string` which gets converted to a double afterwards.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

const double PI = 3.14159;
double rad = 0;
double area = 0;
double vol = 0;
int areaPi = 0;
int volPi = 0;

int width_col1 = 40;

//cout.fill('.');
cout << setprecision(5) << fixed;
cout << left << setw(width_col1) << "Enter radius for the sphere: " << right;
std::string input;
cin  >> input;

rad = stod(input);

area = (4 * PI * (rad * rad));
vol = ((4.0/3.0) * PI * (rad * rad * rad));
areaPi = (4 * (rad *rad));
volPi = (4 * (rad * rad * rad));

int indent = width_col1 + input.length() + 1; 

cout << left << setw(indent - to_string(area).length()) << "Surface area of the sphere: " << area << " (" << areaPi << "\u03C0)" << std::endl;
cout << left << setw(indent - to_string(vol).length()) << "The volume of the sphere:   " << vol << " (" << volPi << "π/3)" << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

- This solution resembles what C programmers would have done with `printf`.
- I would love to learn why this did not work with the input.